# SBT confused about Scala types

Tags: scala, sbt

SBT is throwing the following error:

```
value split is not a member of (String, String)
[error]       .filter(arg => arg.split(delimiter).length >= 2)
```

For the following code block:

```
implicit def argsToMap(args: Array[String]): Map[String, String] = {
val delimiter = "="
args
  .filter(arg => arg.split(delimiter).length >= 2)
  .map(arg => arg.split(delimiter)(0) -> arg.split(delimiter)(1))
  .toMap
}
```

Can anyone explain what might be going on here?
Some details:

```
java version "1.8.0_191"
sbt version 1.2.7
scala version 2.11.8
```

I've tried both on the command line and also with intellij. I've also tried Java 11 and Scala 2.11.12 to no avail.

I'm not able to replicate this on another machine (different OS, SBT, IntelliJ, etc. though) and I can also write a minimal failing case:

```
value split is not a member of (String, String)
[error]     Array("a", "b").map(x => x.split("y"))
```

Comment: There is no `split` method on tuples. But given your code `arg` should not be a `(String, String)` tuple but simply a `String` (which does have a `split` method).

Comment: Indeed @Marth, that's the mystery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the `filter` method is added to arrays via an implicit.
When you call `args.filter(...)`, `args` is converted to `ArrayOps` via the `Predef.refArrayOps` implicit method.

You are defining a implicit conversion from `Array[String]` to `Map[(String, String)]`.
This implicit has higher priority than `Predef.refArrayOps` and is therefore used instead.

So `args` is converted into a `Map[(String, String)]`. The `filter` method of that Map would expect a function of type `(String, String) => Boolean` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what happened is that the implicit method is getting invoked a bit too eagerly. That is, the `Tuple2` that's seemingly coming out of nowhere is the result of the implicit function converting each `String` into a key/value pair. The implicit function was recursively calling itself. I found this out after eventually getting a stack overflow with some other code that was manipulating a collection of `String`s.