# Merge multiple FileInputStreams into single FileInputStream

Tags: scala, merge, fileinputstream

I have situation where I need to merge multiple InputStream into single stream. I tried below code but it only return content from last file / stream. what is wrong with code? And is there a better way to merge multiple streams?

```html
  def mergeInputStreams(l: List[File], accum: SequenceInputStream): SequenceInputStream = l match {
    case Nil => accum
    case x :: xs =>
      val is = new FileInputStream(x.pathAsString)
      mergeInputStreams(xs, new SequenceInputStream(is,  accum))
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but I would use `SequenceInputStream`'s constructor that takes an `Enumeration` of `File`s and just map my input list of files into the right types to feed that:

```
import java.io.{File, FileInputStream, InputStream, SequenceInputStream}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.asJavaEnumeration

def mergeInputStreams(files: Iterator[File]): InputStream =
  new SequenceInputStream(asJavaEnumeration(files.map(new FileInputStream(_))))
```

The other trick is to use Scala's included conversion method to convert from a Scala `Iterator` to a Java `Enumeration`. The conversion preserves the ordering and the fact that it's a traversal over a sequence of files, so it also preserves the input stream concatenation.

Comment: If you `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`, you can write `foo.asJavaEnumeration` instead of `asJavaEnumeration(foo)`.

Comment: And if you import `scala.collection.JavaConversions._` instead, you don't need to write even that, it'll just work :)

Comment: @Dima `JavaConversions` is deprecated in favor of `JavaConverters`

Comment: @Aki I know. "Deprecated" isn't the same thing as "not useful" though

Comment: @Dima imho implicit conversions that you have to explicitly import are confusing more often than they are useful.

Comment: well, implicit conversions are a big part of scala language. If you find scala confusing, I guess, you have a right for that opinion :)
FWIW, I think, conversions that do _not_ have to be imported are actually way more confusing - had my share of pulled hair over "where the hell does this thing come from"  - when you have an `import` statement on the other hand, that's a pretty good hint.

Comment: @Dima implicit conversions of either kind can be confusing :-) e.g., `any2stringadd`. Sure implicit conversions are a big part of Scala, but unprincipled use to convert between types is rightly discouraged, in favour of more principled use like typeclasses or extension methods. I guess I should say, not only are imported implicits confusing but they also force you to figure out where to get them, and then litter the code with imports that take away from the code flow. At least nowadays a good editor tooling can show you the auto-imported conversions.

Comment: I can just agree with @Dima. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732954) just another example of how confusing implicits conversions may get.

Comment: @Yawar :"unprincipled use" - sure. But _my_ use of them is very principled.
Implicts do not "force you to figure out where to get them" any more than, say, collections "force you to figure out how to use them". If you imported them, chances are you know where from :) FWIW, I think exactly _zero_ confusion about a `List` being passed to a java function, where a `Collection` is expected. I think, this particular use of implicit is truly as "principled" as you are ever going to see.\

Comment: @Dima sure, for a simple case like this I figured out where to find the converter function from Scala `Iterator` to Java `Enumeration`. But in the Scala ecosystem there are tons of implicits cordoned off into their own packages that you have to import indiscriminately, prime example: `import cats.implicits._`. Imho it totally destroys efforts to make code as minimalistic as possible. As for your use here, it may be fine but in the general case auto-conversion between unrelated types is just a bad idea ‍♂️

Comment: @Yawar yeah, if you ask me, 99% cases using `cats` do not need it at all, and would be made much cleaner and more readable without it. That is a very different issue though. `JavaConversion` is simple, well known and understood component, that helps readability by removing unnecessary noise from the code without adding any complexity or confusion.